# How to create an asp:button programmatically in c# behind with click handling

Tags: c#, asp.net

i write this code after many search but is not working
i need to create as asp:button programmatically and handling it

```
for(int i=0;i<DtShow.Rows.Count;i++)
        {
            Button btn = new Button
            {
                Text = "حذف",
                ID = i.ToString(),
                UseSubmitBehavior = false,
                CommandArgument =i.ToString(),
                CssClass = "btn btn-danger"
            };
            btn.Click +=new EventHandler(this.btn_Click);
            lstAccessDgv.Rows[i].Cells[2].Controls.Add(btn);
        }
 protected void btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Button b = (Button)sender;
        int id = Convert.ToInt32(b.ID);
        DtCode.Rows.RemoveAt(id);
        DtShow.Rows.RemoveAt(id);
        lstAccessDgv.Rows[id].Visible = false;
    }
```

why not call btn_Click?

Comment: You are probably not recreating the Controls on every page load (and that includes a PostBack).

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately your question doesn't make it clear what information you're looking for, however, since you did make a specific query, I'll address that.

> why not call btn_Click?

Because the `btn_Click` event handler hasn't been bound to the button's click event.

That's why you need to do this when you create the button:

```
btn.Click +=new EventHandler(this.btn_Click);
```

This executes `btn_Click` when the button is clicked.

A thing to keep in mind, though, is that this function will execute for every button in the list so you need to make sure it does work that specifically relates to the list item to which the button belongs.